# Unable to run new .cfg on PlayerStage

Tags: c, ubuntu-12.04, robotics, player-stage

I have successfully installed Player/Stage on Ubuntu 12.04 using this blog:
http://www.cnblogs.com/kevinGuo/archive/2012/05/03/2480077.html

`player simple.cfg` is working fine and is showing the desired results as shown in the above mentioned blog.

Then, I was trying to run empty.cfg after creating empty.cfg and empty.world as explained in this tutorial:
http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/jowen/player/playerstage-tutorial-manual.pdf

But, it is showing this error:

```
cs246@cs246:~/src/Stage-3.2.2-Source/worlds$ player empty.cfg 
Registering driver
Player v.3.0.2

* Part of the Player/Stage/Gazebo Project [http://playerstage.sourceforge.net].
* Copyright (C) 2000 - 2009 Brian Gerkey, Richard Vaughan, Andrew Howard,
* Nate Koenig, and contributors. Released under the GNU General Public License.
* Player comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
* are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions; see COPYING
* for details.

error   : Failed to load plugin libstageplugin.
error   : libtool reports error: file not found
error   : plugin search path: /home/cs246/src/Stage-3.2.2-Source/worlds:.:/usr/local/lib/
error   : failed to load plugin: libstageplugin
error   : failed to parse config file empty.cfg driver blocks
```

Can anyone help me in resolving it.